# how do you pick factor in dplyr summary function

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame tt:

```
structure(list(Hostname = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Server01", class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(1:3, .Label = c("2015-10-01 08:15:00", "2015-10-01 08:30:00", 
    "2015-10-01 10:45:00"), class = "factor"), Cpubusy = c(35.2, 
    17.89, 22.04), Function = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Data Retriever", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Hostname", 
"Date", "Cpubusy", "Function"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I need to calcate Avg, 95th percentile and create a table.

the table should looks something like this:

```
Server AVG  95th_Percentile  Function
Server01  10    30          Data Retriver
```

I tried dplyr summary function like this:

```
cpu<-tt %>% group_by(Hostname) %>% summarise_(Mean = interp(~mean(Cpubusy, na.rm=FALSE)),Quantile= interp(~quantile(Cpubusy, prob=0.95,na.rm=FALSE)),tt$Function)
```

Not able to insert the Function data for each server. Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out, in case if anybody faces this problem, you can group by multiple fields.

This worked for me:

```
cpu<-tt %>% group_by(Hostname,Function) %>% summarise_(Mean = interp(~mean(Cpubusy, na.rm=FALSE)),Quantile= interp(~quantile(Cpubusy, prob=0.95,na.rm=FALSE)))
```